# Find zeros of general sum of sin functions

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

Is there a way to find the zeros (or maximum) of the sum of a finite number of sine functions within some bounds, $x \in [A, B]$? Each sine function can have a different magnitude, offset, and frequency.

$\Sigma_{i=1}^n a_i \sin(xb_i + c_i) = 0$

Comment: Is a numerical solution an acceptable way?

Comment: I'd prefer analytical, but sure... if it's maximum I'd want the global maximum though.

Comment: There exist complete though numerical methods to find __all__ zeros of equation at a given interval. See "Interval Newton Method", https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Interval_Newton's_method